# Is Mongo stable?

Tags: mongodb, chai

I've got some mocha tests shown below. When I run them, they work. And then I run them again and one of them will fail. Then I run them, and they work, and then the next time, some other (seemingly) random test will fail. If I've structured this poorly or coded something wrong, I'm open to hearing that.

Can anyone tell me why these tests fail randomly? It makes me wonder about mongo's stability.

Another thing is: the test never says what went wrong, only that it timed out and that I should ensure that done() is called. The /data/mongoAccess code is below the test block.

```
(function() {
    var assert = require("chai").assert;
    var mongo = require("../data/semRushMongoAccess");

    describe("insertApiCall", function() {
    it("should insert a new record.", function(done) {
        var data = {
            "data": "insertApiCall"
        };
        mongo.removeApiCall("uri1").then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri1", "type", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2", data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri1");
        }).then(function(result) {
            assert.equal("insertApiCall", result[0].data.data);
            return;
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri1");
        }).then(function() {
            done();
        });
    });
    });


    describe("removeApiCall", function() {
    it("should remove a record specified by uri.", function(done) {
        var data = {
            "data": "removeApiCall1"
        };

        mongo.removeApiCall("uri1").then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri2", "type", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2", data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri2");
        }).then(function(result1) {
            assert.equal("removeApiCall1", result1[0].data.data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri2");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri2");
        }).then(function(result2) {
            assert.isArray(result2);
            assert.equal(0, result2.length, "Data was not removed.");
            done();
        });
    });
    it("should remove a record specified by apiType", function(done) {
        var data = {
            "data": "removeApiCall2"
        };

        mongo.removeApiCall("uri3").then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri3", "type", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2", data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri3");
        }).then(function(result1) {
            assert.equal("removeApiCall2", result1[0].data.data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri3");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri3");
        }).then(function(result2) {
            assert.isArray(result2);
            assert.equal(0, result2.length, "Data was not removed.");
            done();
        });
    });
    it("should remove a record specified by domain.", function(done) {
        var data = {
            "data": "removeApiCall3"
        };

        mongo.removeApiCall("uri4").then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri4", "type", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2", data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri4");
        }).then(function(result1) {
            assert.equal("removeApiCall3", result1[0].data.data);
            return mongo.removeApiCall(null, null, "domain");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri4");
        }).then(function(result2) {
            assert.isArray(result2);
            assert.equal(0, result2.length, "Data was not removed.");
            done();
        });
    });
    it("should remove a record specified by target.", function(done) {
        var data = {
            "data": "removeApiCall4"
        };

        mongo.removeApiCall("uri5").then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri5", "type", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2", data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri5");
        }).then(function(result1) {
            assert.equal("removeApiCall4", result1[0].data.data);
            return mongo.removeApiCall(null, null, null, "target");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri5");
        }).then(function(result2) {
            assert.isArray(result2);
            assert.equal(0, result2.length, "Data was not removed.");
            done();
        });
    });
    it("should remove a record specified by url.", function(done) {
        var data = {
            "data": "removeApiCall5"
        };

        mongo.removeApiCall("uri6").then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri6", "type", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2", data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri6");
        }).then(function(result1) {
            assert.equal("removeApiCall5", result1[0].data.data);
            return mongo.removeApiCall(null, null, null, null, "url");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri6");
        }).then(function(result2) {
            assert.isArray(result2);
            assert.equal(0, result2.length, "Data was not removed.");
            done();
        });
    });
    it("should remove a record specified by phrase.", function(done) {
        var data = {
            "data": "removeApiCall6"
        };

        mongo.removeApiCall("uri7").then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri7", "type", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2", data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri7");
        }).then(function(result1) {
            assert.equal("removeApiCall6", result1[0].data.data);
            return mongo.removeApiCall(null, null, null, null, null, "phrase");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri7");
        }).then(function(result2) {
            assert.isArray(result2);
            assert.equal(0, result2.length, "Data was not removed.");
            done();
        });
    });
    it("should remove a record specified by domains", function(done) {
        var data = {
            "data": "removeApiCall7"
        };
        mongo.removeApiCall("uri8").then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri8", "type", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2", data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri8");
        }).then(function(result1) {
            assert.equal("removeApiCall7", result1[0].data.data);
            return mongo.removeApiCall(null, null, null, null, null, null, "d1|d2");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri8");
        }).then(function(result2) {
            assert.isArray(result2);
            assert.equal(0, result2.length, "Data was not removed.");
            done();
        });
    });
    it("should remove records using OR when isOr is true.", function(done) {
        var data = {
            "data": "removeApiCall8"
        };
        mongo.removeApiCall("uri9").then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri10");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri9", "type1", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d1", data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri10", "type2", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri9", "type2", null, null, null, null, null, true);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri9", "type2", null, null, null, null, null, true)
        }).then(function(result) {
            assert.isArray(result);
            assert.equal(0, result.length, "Array length is " + result.length);
            done();
        });
    });
    it("should remove records using AND when isOr is false.", function(done) {
        var data = {
            "data": "removeApiCall9"
        };

        // Insert uri11/type1, uri12/type1, and uri12/type2
        // Remove uri12 + type1.
        // Should leave uri11 and uri12/type2.
        mongo.removeApiCall("uri11").then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri12");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri11", "type1", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d1", data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri12", "type1", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri12", "type2", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2")
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri12", "type1", null, null, null, null, null, false);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri12");
        }).then(function(result) {
            assert.isArray(result);
            assert.equal(1, result.length, "Array length is " + result.length);
            assert.equal("type2", result[0].apiType);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri11");
        }).then(function(result2) {
            assert.isArray(result2);
            assert.equal(1, result2.length);
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri11");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri12");
        }).then(function() {
            done();
        });
    });
    it("should remove records using AND when isOr is not specified (is null).", function(done) {
        var data = {
            "data": "removeApiCall9"
        };

        // Identical to previous test, only instead of explicit false for isOr, it's excluded.
        // Insert uri11/type1, uri12/type1, and uri12/type2
        // Remove uri12 + type1.
        // Should leave uri11 and uri12/type2.
        mongo.removeApiCall("uri11").then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri12");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri11", "type1", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d1", data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri12", "type1", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri12", "type2", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2")
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri12", "type1", null, null, null, null, null);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri12");
        }).then(function(result) {
            assert.isArray(result);
            assert.equal(1, result.length, "Array length is " + result.length);
            assert.equal("type2", result[0].apiType);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri11");
        }).then(function(result2) {
            assert.isArray(result2);
            assert.equal(1, result2.length);
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri11");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri12");
        }).then(function() {
            done();
        });
    });
    });
})();
```

mongoAccess:

```
(function() {
    var moment = require("moment");
    var appConfig = require("../config/appConfig");
    var mongo = require("promised-mongo");
    var db = mongo("mongodb://localhost:27017/" + appConfig.options.dbName, ["apiCalls"]);

    exports.insertApiCall = function(uri, apiType, lineLimit, domain, target, url, phrase, domains, data) {
    return db.apiCalls.insert({
        uri: uri,
        apiType: apiType,
        lineLimit: lineLimit,
        domain: domain,
        target: target,
        url: url,
        phrase: phrase,
        domains: domains,
        data: data,
        timestamp: moment.utc().format()
    });
    };

    exports.findApiCall = function(uri, apiType, domain, target, url, phrase, domains, isOr) {
    var query = buildQuery(uri, apiType, domain, target, url, phrase, domains, isOr);
    var resultSet = buildResultSet(uri, apiType, domain, target, url, phrase, domains);
    return db.apiCalls.find(query, resultSet);
    };

    exports.removeApiCall = function(uri, apiType, domain, target, url, phrase, domains, isOr) {
    var query = buildQuery(uri, apiType, domain, target, url, phrase, domains, isOr);
    return db.apiCalls.remove(query);
    };

    function buildResultSet(uri, domain, target, url, phrase, domains) {
    var resultSet = {
        "apiType": true,
        "timestamp": true,
        "data": true
    };

    if (uri != null) {
        resultSet["uri"] = true;
    }
    if (domain != null) {
        resultSet["domain"] = true;
    }
    if (target != null) {
        resultSet["target"] = true;
    }
    if (url != null) {
        resultSet["url"] = true;
    }
    if (phrase != null) {
        resultSet["phrase"] = true;
    }
    if (domains != null) {
        resultSet["domains"] = true;
    }
    return resultSet;
    }

    function buildQuery(uri, apiType, domain, target, url, phrase, domains, isOr) {
    var query = [];

    if (uri != null) {
        query.push({
            uri: uri
        });
    }
    if (apiType != null) {
        query.push({
            apiType: apiType
        });
    }
    if (domain != null) {
        query.push({
            domain: domain
        });
    }
    if (target != null) {
        query.push({
            target: target
        });
    }
    if (url != null) {
        query.push({
            url: url
        });
    }
    if (phrase != null) {
        query.push({
            phrase: phrase
        });
    }
    if (domains != null) {
        query.push({
            domains: domains
        });
    }

    return isOr ? {
        $or: query
    } : {
        $and: query
    };
}
})();
```

Comment: I would suggest tests on your implemented wrapping API and the logic contained within. Having such strict signatures is something I would suggest to be not a good thing as well as there being a lot of conditional checking to just assign fields where you could do this a lot more organically. Also just saying "random fail" is not really descriptive of the problem or problems you are facing. Better to be descriptive here about specific errors or unexpected results, and with reproducible cases.

Comment: The specific error, as I stated is the timeout: Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test. I don't know how else to describe the behavior when a different test fails each time and sometimes, no test fails. I'm open to suggestions on what better language could be used to describe that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Unfortunately, I changed the text of my question before realizing that I had fixed the problem with the change. I can no longer reproduce the problem after fixing my promise syntax.

I was doing something like this:

```
 mongo.removeApiCall("uri11").then(
     mongo.removeApiCall("uri12").then(
         mongo.insertApiCall("uri11", "type1", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d1", data).then(
             mongo.insertApiCall("uri12", "type1", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2").then(
                 mongo.insertApiCall("uri12", "type2", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2").then(
                     mongo.removeApiCall("uri12", "type1", null, null, null, null, null, false).then(
                         mongo.findApiCall("uri12").then(function(result) {
                             assert.isArray(result);
                             assert.equal(1, result.length, "Array length is " + result.length);
                             assert.equal("type2", result[0].apiType);
                             mongo.findApiCall("uri11").then(function(result2) {
                                 assert.isArray(result2);
                                 assert.equal(1, result2.length);
                                 mongo.removeApiCall("uri11").then(
                                     mongo.removeApiCall("uri12").then(function() {
                                         done();
                                     }));
                             });
                         })))))));
```

and when I switched it to this:

```
      mongo.removeApiCall("uri11").then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri12");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri11", "type1", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d1", data);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri12", "type1", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.insertApiCall("uri12", "type2", 2, "domain", "target", "url", "phrase", "d1|d2")
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri12", "type1", null, null, null, null, null, false);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri12");
        }).then(function(result) {
            assert.isArray(result);
            assert.equal(1, result.length, "Array length is " + result.length);
            assert.equal("type2", result[0].apiType);
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.findApiCall("uri11");
        }).then(function(result2) {
            assert.isArray(result2);
            assert.equal(1, result2.length);
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri11");
        }).then(function() {
            return mongo.removeApiCall("uri12");
        }).then(function() {
            done();
        });
```

the problem disappeared. I'm not really sure why this is the case, but like I said, I haven't been able to reproduce the problem since making this change.